# Listbox displayMember not working

Tags: c#, listbox, listboxitems

I have run into an issue.
I am creating a small application for working with our phone configuration files.
I have created a Class called Phone and given it 4 properties:

```
private int extension;
private String sExtension;
private String userName;
private String filePath;
```

I have included the respective get/set methods as well as:

```
public String Extension
{
    get
    {
        return sExtension;
    }
}
public String Path
{
    get
    {
        return filePath;
    }
}
```

I have created a utility class that does most of the static work.  Including a method to create a `List<Phone>` of phone objects to populate the `ListBox`.

Everything works to the point of returning the `List<Phone>` back as the datasource for the `ListBox`.  I have set both the:

```
fileList = Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "ext-*");
lst_Files.DataSource = Utility.populatePhoneList(fileList);
lst_Files.DisplayMember = "Extension";
lst_Files.ValueMember = "Path";
```

The problem I am still experiencing is the `ListBox` is still being populated by the object name (in reference to [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1))

I have read through a couple articles on this forum and most mention the same issue that I may not be calling `ListBox.DisplayMember` correctly but I believe I am.

Edit: I have tried returning a `List<T>`, `ArrayList`,`Array[]`.

Edit: Code for utility

```
public static List<Phone> populatePhoneList(IEnumerable<String> newFileList)
{
    List<Phone> phones = new List<Phone>();
    Phone p = null;

    for (int i = 0; i < newFileList.Count(); i++)
    {
        p = getPhoneInfo(newFileList.ElementAt(i));
        phones.Add(p);
    }
    return phones;
}

public static Phone getPhoneInfo(String newPath)
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(newPath);
    Phone p1 = new Phone();
    p1.setFilePath(newPath);            
    String testLine;

    while (sr.Peek() >= 0)
    {
        testLine = sr.ReadLine();
        if (testLine.Contains("reg.1.displayName"))
            p1.setUserName(testLine.Substring(testLine.IndexOf("\"") + 1, ((testLine.LastIndexOf("\"") - 1) - testLine.IndexOf("\""))));
        if (testLine.Contains("reg.1.address"))
            p1.setExtension(testLine.Substring(testLine.IndexOf("\"") + 1, ((testLine.LastIndexOf("\"") - 1) - testLine.IndexOf("\""))));
    }
    return p1;
}
```

Comment: Code looks ok.  We would have to see your `Utility.populatePhoneList` function, I'm guessing.

Comment: can you show the code for Utility.populatePhoneList(fileList)

Comment: After digging into this problem over the weekend I started disabling some event handlers on the `ListBox` and found that it is working as it should be.  I found that my `ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event was catching the list before the system completely populated.  My solution was to turn `ListBox.SelectionMode` to none then reset it once the `ListBox` was filled.

Answer (score 2):

After digging into this problem over the weekend I started disabling some event handlers on the `ListBox` and found that it is working as it should be.  I found that my `ListBox.SelectedIndexChanged` event was catching the list before the system completely populated.  My solution was to turn `ListBox.SelectionMode` to none then reset it once the `ListBox` was filled.